# Why might a Java findClass() call be taking 7 minutes on Tomcat 8.5?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, classloader

I am trying to investigate a performance issue on an Java app deployed with a standalone Tomcat 8.5 instance. The application is occasionally freezing for 5-10 minutes and becoming unresponsive to user queries, roughly once every 24 hours. The application is packaged as a war file but unpacked as part of the deployment process.

By enabling stuck thread detection in logging, we identified that threads were getting stuck loading classes:

```
27-Mar-2021 19:21:46.045 WARNING [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve.notifyStuckThreadDetected Thread [http-nio-8080-exec-8] (id=[70]) has been active for [308,580] milliseconds (since [3/27/21 7:16 PM]) to serve the same request for [http://gms-beta.beta.euw2.vi.basespace.illumina.com/hadean-api/user/login-urls] and may be stuck (configured threshold for this StuckThreadDetectionValve is [300] seconds). There is/are [1] thread(s) in total that are monitored by this Valve and may be stuck.
    java.lang.Throwable
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:202)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.openJarFile(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:308)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:280)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2278)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:855)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1327)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createWithCustomLookup(MetaClassRegistry.java:149)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.create(MetaClassRegistry.java:144)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:270)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:313)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:323)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:262)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:879)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createPojoSite(CallSiteArray.java:125)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:166)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
        at com.ilmn.hadean.controller.UserController.getAppConfig(UserController.groovy:217)
        at com.ilmn.hadean.controller.UserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7cdc282f.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:180)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
        at com.ilmn.hadean.controller.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3259232e.getAppConfig(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.ilmn.hadean.filter.XssFilter.doFilterInternal(XssFilter.java:26)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:209)
        at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:244)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(StuckThreadDetectionValve.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1626)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Enabling logging on the class loader, I can see that findClass() calls are taking an extremely long time - most of the time it takes milliseconds to load a class, but the helpful stuck thread detection find a number of threads in which this step of class loading takes entire minutes. In this case the findClass() method is called at 09:25, and does not return until 09:32!

```
30-Mar-2021 09:25:20.191 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-46] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass loadClass(org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartResolutionDelegate, false)
30-Mar-2021 09:25:20.191 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-46] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass loadClass(org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartResolutionDelegate, false)
30-Mar-2021 09:25:20.191 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-46] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass     findClass(org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartResolutionDelegate)
30-Mar-2021 09:32:26.342 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-46] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass       Returning class class org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartResolutionDelegate
```

Any insights into what's going on here very much appreciated! What tools can I use to narrow down the source of this delay, and what configuration can I tweak to get rid of it?

From reading around, it sounds like a way to stop classes getting unloaded in the first place would solve the problem, but understanding why this operation is taking so long in the first place and fixing that would be ideal.

---

**Some additional context:**

- We are seeing this behaviour with different classes provided by different source jar files.
- We have seen it in different builds of the same Tomcat/Spring Boot 2 application
- We are seeming this issue sporadically in several different environments - but not at all in others.
- These environments are very low utilisation (so it would make sense for classes to be unloaded), but we have not been able to reproduce the issue even in developer environments that have been idle for 24h+.
- We see similar performance issues on first boot fairly consistently - but also later after the environment has been sat idle!

Because of the latter reason, we theorise that classes getting unloaded dynamically by Tomcat is a factor here.

One  factor the environments where we are seeeing this issue have in common is having outbound internet access restricted. I am curious if there is any way in which the Tomcat classloader might rely on outbound internet access - from what I understand, the [findClass()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoaderBase.html#findClass(java.lang.String)) method will be looking in its local repositories in the classpath - in this case part of the default classpath at `${CATALINA_HOME}/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` - not anywhere over the internet.

---

**Reference:**

Configuration for gathering this information, in case it's useful to anyone else:

To enable the Stuck Thread Detection value, add the following to `${CATALINA_BASE}/conf/server.xml` inside the    element:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8080"/>


        <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3"/>


        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"/>

            ...
            ...

            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve" threshold="300" /> 

        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Set the `threshold` value set to the number of seconds to wait before classifying a thread as stuck - in this case it is set to 300 seconds (5 minutes).

To capture verbose class loading information, add the following to `${CATALINA_BASE}/conf/logging.properties`. Beware it is very verbose:

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.level=ALL
```

Comment: Since it gets stuck on JREs native code, I would check the integrity of the JREs. Which OS and JRE (exact) version are you using?

Comment: That makes sense! AdoptOpenJDK, build 1.8.0_282-b08, and Amazon Linux which is based on RHEL Fedora.